# Infinite loops in multiprocessing python

Tags: python, while-loop, python-multiprocessing

How do I get the notworking() to work in mulitprossesing. My console is only logging whyisthis(). I am new to multiprosessing, and I am just not getting this, so I hope someone will give an easy solution.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def whyisthis():
    while True:
        print(f'Why is this')
        time.sleep(5)


def notworking():
    while True:
        print(f'not working')


p1 = Process(target=whyisthis(), daemon=False, 
name='Why is this')
p2 = Process(target=notworking(), daemon=False, 
name='Not working')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: You meant to write: `target=whyisthis, daemon ...` and `target=notworking, daemon ...`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code lies here:

```
p1 = Process(target=whyisthis(), daemon=False, name="Why is this")
```

the target should be a funcion but in your code you **execute** the function here with brackets. That is like normal function calling so that's why your program just stuck on that line (or more precisely - execute whyisthis which never ends).

Correct way should be

```
p1 = Process(target=whyisthis, daemon=False, name="Why is this")
```